# How to sort multiple columns/custom sort a visual, not table level?

Tags: powerbi

I want to display information on a weekly basis and when the user clicks on the week number, it drills down to the day of the week sorted by Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc...

I want it to be sorted on the visual only and not by sorting it at the Table level or creating a new data source.
I do not want a new data source for sorting with Index because if I have 3 visual using column A and I want to sort it differently, I will have to create 3 tables to index them A to 1, B to 2, C to 3, D to 4, E to 5 or
C to 2, D to 3, E to 4, F to 5, etc..

In tableau the you can sort each measure/dimension individually.

Is there any equivalent solution in power bi? Also, I dont have the option to sort by 2 values or have a custom sort in the visual, why?

Thanks

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

**UPDATE: There is no other way to do it in Power BI other than creating a table and a column which will be used to sort your visual. If you use the visual multiple times and have different sorting per visual, a new column in the table and sort using the column**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This domain falls under custom sort. You need to create a key table defining logically ordering and create a relationship with the original column, then perform sorting of table with key values scale (Sunday 1, Monday 2....)

You may also see attached reference link for custom column creation and sorting.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.seerinteractive.com/blog/reorder-powerbi-legend/%3famp=1

Comment: Isnt there any other way than creating a new table? I can have multiple viz and each one uses Day of the Week for sorting but those Viz are not necessarily sorted the same way. Maybe I want A,B,C and in another one I want C,A,B. I cannot create a key/table for each of them.

Comment: By default the legend value are shown alphabetical sorted, to achieve desired outcome key column is one effictive way and easy to control as well if the requirement changes.

Comment: It is but not when you have multiple viz using same key/table you want to sort dynamically. Maybe because I used Tableau before thats why I am seeing a limitation in Power BI on it

Comment: Its not limitation i guess but yes change pattern and technology and way to doing in a different manner.

Comment: @Jonathan is it kindly possible to provide a sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate table for each sort, just a separate column.

The best-practice way to handle this situation would be to have a date dimension table that has all of the columns you'd like to use on your axis as well as column specifying their order where it that isn't the same as the default.

If you create a date dimension table you can use it any visual where you need to use a date. This is what the relevant columns would look like:

| Date | Week | WeekInt | Weekday | WeekdayInt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | Week 0 | 0 | Fri | 5 |
| 1/2/2021 | Week 0 | 0 | Sat | 6 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

Using a table like this, you'd set `Week` to sort by `WeekInt` and `Weekday` to sort by `WeekdayInt`, which would make those columns sort properly on any visual that uses them.

---

Please see the following resources for more about date dimension tables:

https://radacad.com/do-you-need-a-date-dimension

https://radacad.com/create-a-date-dimension-in-power-bi-in-4-steps-step-1-calendar-columns